# Best way to build a SMART mySQL & PHP search engine?

Tags: php, mysql, search

What is the best way to build a mySQL & PHP search?

I am currently using things like

> %term%

I want it to be able to find the result even if they spell it slightly wrong, for example:

Field value = "One: Stop Shop:

They search:

One Shop Stop

OR

One Stop Shop

Etc.. I want a really smart search so they find the information even if they don't search the exact thing.

What is the best way to build a smart search like this?

Comment: Why not try some tutorials like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pW7mGr8oAU or http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Building-a-Search-Engine-with-MySQL-and-PHP-5/1/

Comment: Why bother re-inventing the wheel when there's perfectly good pre-built ones? Look up Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and Sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`like '%term%'` is terrible slow and unoptimized , you might want to add full-text for this column, and [use boolean mode for this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Such as

```
match(column) against('+One +Shop +Stop' in boolean mode)
```

Take note on the min word lengths is 4, so, you need to consider change it to three, and full-text search only available for myisam

Other opensource search engine like [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is ideal for this too

Comment: ajreal is right. you need to add a full-text index to the field you would like to search against. then do a match statement to do the actual search. you can even order by the relevance. google for more details.

Comment: Make sure you have plenty of test data if you are testing full-text indexes, if the results found are greater than 50% of the number of total records, it counts this as a failed search.  This could interfere with your sanity if you did not know it.  I'm OK now though.

Answer (score 7):

[`Ajreal`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466826/ajreal) is right...just thought I'd add an example to help out:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT *, 
         MATCH(col1, col2) AGAINST('%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
     FROM my_table
     ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 20", $keyword);
$rs = $conn->query($query);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

You cannot be most efficient by searching on your raw data. This kind of text searching depends on how the data is indexed (this is where Google bot comes in for Google).

So, step 1 is indexing. If your data is in some web pages, you can use standard crawlers available (or even build your own crawler easily, I would suggest python for building crawler). If your data is in some file (not web browsable), then for indexing, you need to write a program to read all data and index them.

Step 2 is searching. Searching approach depend on indexing strategy.

If you are looking for php-mysql based system, review the codes of these projects:

http://www.phpdig.net/

http://sphinxsearch.com/

If you want to know more, search in IEEE Xplore/ACM publications archives. You will get lots of papers published on this topic.

Comment: What if I have 300,000 + pages?

Comment: If you really need to index 300,000+ pages, you better read on topics such as "Distributed Search Techniques". Using MySQL will not be much efficient for large data set. You will need your own file system. Fortunately, you may use some open sourse file system. Practically, we have a specialized crawler (not publicly open). We handle gigabytes of data. We have our own filesystem and we put our entire data and crawler in Amazon cloud. The cost of Amazon cloud is worth it.

Comment: If you are not in mood for searching papers, at least get a copy of "Lucene in Action" (ISBN 1-932394-28-1). You can get some summary. Also, you can use Lucene (Java based). But in your question, you asked for a php-mysql solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SOUNDEX() function , it's available in both PHP and MYSQL 
[SOUNDEX() with MYSQL](http://www.madirish.net/67)

Comment: This may or may not be useful in the OP's case. For example, the soundex codes for "stop" and "shop" are different.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple, Smart and Secure**

As [`timpng1`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967604/timpng1) put an example on [`Ajreal`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466826/ajreal) [`Answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643615/13378977) above I'd like to make it **Secure**.

```
$conn = new mysqli('server', 'username', 'password', 'dbName');
$q = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET["query"]);
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, MATCH(col1, col2) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM my_table ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 20");
$sql->bind_param("s", $q);
$sql->execute();
$rs = $sql->get_result();
```